# C ::PlaySound loop sound at loop start end

Tags: c++, windows, audio

I'm trying to loop a sound, but I can only find `SND_LOOP` to loop the entire sound, for `PlaySound()` in C++.  Is there any way to have it, when it goes to loop, have it loop around a loop start/end point.   Or if that's impossible in `PlaySound`, any other API (I have DirectX 9.0c use).

Comment: [`PlaySound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680.aspx) is neither MFC nor C++. It's Windows API and C. Regardless, you have not made clear why you cannot use it, or what precisely want to achieve.

Comment: I didn't realize, sorry about that.  My goal is to loop a wav sound, but not the entire sound, from a loop start and end (like from sample 3 to sample 100), for count # times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find anything, but I ended up truncating the wave to a second, loop only one, and playing that in a loop.